# Unable to view Main Activity changes on the AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am unable to view my `mainactivity` changes onto the AVD like the button and any transitions. Although the menu is clearly visible. I am just able to see the see the menu bar and no button is visible in the AVD

```
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn= findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myLayout=findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
            new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    movebtn();
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;

}
public void movebtn(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionrules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    positionrules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
   btn.setLayoutParams(positionrules);
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizerules = btn.getLayoutParams();
   sizerules.width=400;
   sizerules.height=300;
   btn.setLayoutParams(sizerules);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.settings_menu:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.alarm_menu:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: show you `R.layout.activity_main` layout file and maybe some printscreen. also exchange `OnTouchListener` for `OnClickListener`

Comment: Main Acitvity.java][1]
        [Main Activity.java][2]
        [ActivityMain.Xml][3]
        [Menu.Xml][4]
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwOma.png
          [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYSB.png
          [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKW98.png
          [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQEAB.png

Comment: These are the links to the images as I am new to stack overflow I am unable to figure out how to add them in text

Comment: first of all: never post text as image, no one will be rewritting this if find any bug... second: below your question you have "edit" label. meritum: standard `AppCompatActivity` doesn't have `onCreate` method taking two arguments, only one `Bundle savedInstanceState`. if your app is building properly then I bet your custom `AppCompatActivity` is a problem. what version of support or androidx libs you are using?